Selenium Slider "Element is not Interactable"
I want to click an active slider to uncheck it. It is the first "Legitimate Interest" while "Managing your Data" on Gmailnator.
def Mailnator():
     #Setzt die Startoptionen als Inkognito Modus und das der BRAVE Browser genutzt werden soll
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chrome_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe"

    #Öffnet Gmailnator mit den vorher gesetzten Startoptionen
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://www.emailnator.com")

    #Alles ablehnen und Optionen auf Gmailnator setzen
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "fc-button.fc-cta-manage-options.fc-secondary-button").click()
    #wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    #wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='fc-preference-slider-purpose-2']"))).click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='fc-preference-slider-purpose-2']").click()

     #Ohne das hier schließt das Fenster sobald der letzte Schritt, hier Passwort einfügen, ausgeführt wurde sofort.
    while (True):
        pass

Mailnator()

Whenever the script reaches this Step i get the error "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

I tried waiting until maybe it is visible (it´s still in the code but i put an # before it) but then i get the error "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:"
When i try to locate the XPATH from " span class="fc-slider-el"></span " it works but on the wrong checkbox (It just checks the checkbox at the top, i guess because the expression in html is the same for both)
